# Let $f(x)$ be irreducible so that $\operatorname{Gal}(f(x)) \simeq Z_{p}$ for p an odd prime. Show that $f(x)$ has degree p and all real zeros.

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I know that if $\operatorname{Gal}(f(x)) \simeq Z_{p}$, then $|\operatorname{Gal}(f(x))| = |Z_{p}| = p$. Does this imply that $deg(f(x)) = p$? How do I go about showing that $f(x)$ only has real roots? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember to exclude $p=2$, for which $Gal(x^2+1)=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\pm i\notin\mathbb{R}$ are roots.

Comment: @deyore The title (but not the body) of the question does say "odd prime".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is irreducible, then its degree must be $p$.

If $f$ is irreducible with some non-real zeros, and $L$ is its
splitting field within $\Bbb C$ then complex conjugation induces
an automorphism of $L$ with order $2$. Thus the Galois group
of $L$ must have even order...

Comment: It may be worth expanding on why $\deg f$ needs to be $p$. As is, it really looks like you are saying that "if $f$ is irreducible over $K$ then $\deg f=|Gal(f/K)|$" which it is not true.